# AJAX before leaving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this question was often asked, but most of the answers are old and the settings are changed now.

**How can I use AJAX right before the user is leaving the page?**

JQuery removed unload() in version 3.0.

And `window.beforeunload` only working with the safety question, if the user is sure about closing the page and losing his input.

But I don't want that question, is there any possibility that for an delay in the beforeunload function?

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){

    var timeOnPage = [
        end = Date.now(),
        elapsed = end - start
    ];

    $.ajax({
        url: 'tracking_userTime_server.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'timeOnPage': timeOnPage
        }
    });

    /*var c=confirm(); //Safety question
    if(c){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }*/
});
```

Comment: This is one of the few scenarios where a sync request is required, so set `async: false`. Note that in recent updated some browsers will not allow blocking calls in the `beforeunload` event so make sure you test to ensure this works in all browsers you need to support

Comment: Take a look at [navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)